# Сломается ли аккумулятор планшета если долгое время его не заряжать?

Tags: samsung

В планшете сломалось гнездо , уже три месяца без зарядки. Где-то слышала что в таком случае аккумулятор сломается . Правда ли это?

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что вопрос не по тематике ресурса

Comment: [Второе правило: Тотальная разрядка нужна раз в квартал](https://batteryk.com/li-ion-akkumulyatory-kak-pravilno-zaryazhat#i-7) (но лучше сами в гугле поищите, может и другие рекомендации есть)